# Best practices for exposing types over the web

Tags: c#, json, wcf, http, types

What is considered the best way to expose a type to another application over the web?

I know that this is possible by creating a type defined in a web service (WCF).  Although, the consuming application wouldn't actually be making any method/service calls.  Would it still be advisable to do this?  Is there a better alternative?

Edit 1:
There is a website that needs to invoke our PC application.  We are using a custom registered protocol which will allow them to pass query-string parameters to us.  Many of these parameters are currently defined as Enum types.  My goal is to expose these types so that the calling website is able to serialize the data and pass it via the query string safely.

Edit 2: Would JSON be a good way to achieve this?  I haven't really delved into it too much but reading an overview seems like it would be a great alternative to what I've been rambling on about ;)

Comment: why would you want to do this? wouldn't sending out a dll be easier?

Comment: There are many ways... SOAP, XML, json... why don't you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Web service are good to expose either (1) functionality or (2) data. What you are asking for seems to be a mix of both. Which is to expose data (encapsulated in a type) with a functionality over this data. Can you please provide the motive for that? Most of the time, you would need one over the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about exposing **complex types** for webservices:

My webservices have either simple standard types linke integer or boolean or strings that contain xml for complex data.

the xml can be described by xsd-files to verify the content. There are also tools for many platforms that generate source code from xsd for the objectmodell. (i.e xsd.exe for Dotnet) there

```
> Best practices for exposing types over the web
```

I would use xsd.

If you want your api with structred types insted of xml you have to process yourself the article [Contract-First Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx) my be helpful